# A function that uses Twitter's API to follow an account

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm trying to create an application in PHP that takes a list of Twitter accounts, each one with its password, and that goes through the list, and starts following a certain Twitter account I provide.

For example, if the provided account is TestUser, and the list is:

test1
test2
test3

Then test1, test2 and test3 would start following TestUser.

How can I create a function in PHP using Twitter's API that provided a Twitter account and its password, and an account, the first account starts following the second one?

Comment: With the current API, it's not possible to authorize with user/password. You have to follow the OAuth flow.

Comment: Thanks. And how would it be with OAuth?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to authenticate using the OAuth flow. There are several libraries that can aid with this process. [Here's a javascript library](https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-js) on GitHub with examples on how to authenticate with the library. Once you've authenticated you would want to use the [friendships/create method](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/friendships/create).